# Is there a material component for Simple Dialog?

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components, material-components-android

As mentioned [here](https://material.io/components/dialogs/#usage), under the different types of Dialogs, the Simple Dialog is listed. Is there a dialog builder that would automatically generate such dialog? Is it just an alert dialog with a custom theme?
I would like to replicate a dialog similar to the new permissions dialogs used in Android 10.
[image]
 I have tried using the material alert dialog builder:

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Message")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
            .setNegativeButton("Ok", null)
            .show();
```

But this shows the options horizontally, whereas I would like to have them vertically. **I have many custom dialogs in my app so I could create another one exactly as I need it, but I wanted to get a better understanding of what's ready to use with the material components instead.**

For that reason I downloaded the [material-components-android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) project from github, where I found the DialogMainDemoFragment which lists different types of dialogs. The one that is closer to what I want is created like so:

```
addDialogLauncher(
        dialogLaunchersLayout,
        R.string.long_title_message_too_long_actions,
        new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getContext())
            .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.long_title))
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.too_long_positive), null)
            .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.too_long_negative), null)
            .setNeutralButton(getResources().getString(R.string.too_long_neutral), null));
```

where

```
private void addDialogLauncher(
      ViewGroup viewGroup, @StringRes int stringResId, AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder) {
    MaterialButton dialogLauncherButton = new MaterialButton(viewGroup.getContext());
    dialogLauncherButton.setOnClickListener(v -> alertDialogBuilder.show());
    dialogLauncherButton.setText(stringResId);
    viewGroup.addView(dialogLauncherButton);
  }
```

but I can't see where the styling/theming is being determined.

Comment: Override those styles
<item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog</item>

more details https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md

Comment: @StanislavParkhomenko I'd seen that, but I'm not so sure how to use them and change the horizontal display of options into vertical. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is material theme which values you can override.
Exactly if I not mistaken you need those styles

```
    <style name="MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Panel.CenterStacked" parent="Base.MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Panel">
       <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had to add a few more attributes to get the desired effect but at least your answer works in showing the options vertically!